# insert value to update foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I´m sorry for the title. It is just that I have no idea how to put this doubt, so just try to realize my goal.

I have two tables: player and team. My doubt is how to add 5 player, using 
relationship one-to-many like one team for 5 player and I tried to update
the player id in team but it just returns the last player id.

```
create table if not exists player (
    p_id int auto_increment not null,
    p_name varchar(100) not null,
    p_number int not null,
    primary key (p_id)
);

create table if not exists team (
    t_id int not null auto_increment,
    t_name varchar(100) not null,
    t_player_id int null,
    primary key (t_id)
);

alter table team add constraint t_pk_player foreign key (t_player_id)
references player(p_id) on delete cascade;
```

`stored prodecure` to create `player` and return `id`

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure sp_create_player(in newName varchar(100), 
                                  in newNumber int, 
                                  out id_player int)
begin
    insert into player (p_name, p_number) values (newName, newNumber);
    -- get the id of player
    set id_player := last_insert_id();
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

`stored prodecure` to create `team` and return `id`

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure sp_create_team(in newName varchar(100), out id_team int)
begin
    insert into team (t_name) values (newName);
    -- get the id of teams
    set id_team := last_insert_id();
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and my doubt his in this `stored prodecure` to `add player` to `team`

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure sp_add_player_in_team(in teamId int, in playerId int)
begin
    -- I tried to make set but it´s not work
    update team set t_player_id = playerId where t_id = teamId;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

testing `stored procedure`

```
-- 5 player
call sp_create_player('De Gea', 1, @id_player1);
call sp_create_player('Rojo', 2, @id_player2);
call sp_create_player('Pogba', 3, @id_player3);
call sp_create_player('Rashford', 4, @id_player4);
call sp_create_player('Ibrahimovic', 5, @id_player5);

-- 1 team
call sp_create_team('Manchester United', @id_team);

-- select all player and team
SELECT * FROM player;
SELECT * FROM team;

-- add 5 player to team
call sp_add_player_in_team(@id_team, @id_player1);
call sp_add_player_in_team(@id_team, @id_player2);
call sp_add_player_in_team(@id_team, @id_player3);
call sp_add_player_in_team(@id_team, @id_player4);
call sp_add_player_in_team(@id_team, @id_player5);

-- select all player in team
SELECT t_player_id FROM team WHERE t_id = @id_team;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You said I have three tables..but I see only two being mentioned. Is it a typo?

Comment: it´s just two table, my mistake but It´s already edit

Comment: You are updating team not inserting new row. This way you get only last player id (from last called procedure sp_add_player_in_team).
Try to make third table with id_team,id_player columns or insert into team table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely representing the relationship either backwards or too simply. If players belong to a team, and only one team, the player records should reference team records.

If players can be on multiple teams, you will have a many-to-many relationship; this requires an additional table linking players to the team(s) they are on (and consequently teams to the players who are on them).

*The only scenarios where you might want a team to directly reference a player is if you were using such a reference to specify team "captain" or something similar where there is only one for a team. If you allowed co-captains, or wanted to specific a player's role on that team, then it'd probably be better as a column on the linking table.*